# How to find if a point is inside a mesh?

Tags: python, mesh

I need a python script that would help me determine if a point is inside a cylindrical mesh.

I tried the .pointInside(point, selected_all=False) but it is deprecated in the newer versions of blender and google search yielded a couple of scripts (below) and they don't work for me.

Ray-casting method: (http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?228683-Point-in-mesh-scripts-not-working)

```
import bpy
import mathutils
def pointInsideMesh(point,ob):
 axes = [ mathutils.Vector((1,0,0)) ]
 outside = False
 for axis in axes:
    mat = ob.matrix_world
    mat.invert()
    orig = mat*point
    count = 0
    while True:
        location,normal,index = ob.ray_cast(orig,orig+axis*10000.0)
        if index == -1: break
        count += 1
        orig = location + axis*0.00001
    if count%2 == 0:
        outside = True
        break
return not outside
print(pointInsideMesh( mathutils.Vector((3,0,0)),bpy.context.active_object))
```

And one described here (http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?228683-Point-in-mesh-scripts-not-working)

```
## normals should be pointing out
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
cur = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location.copy()
cur = obj.matrix_world.inverted() * cur
cpom = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(cur)
vec = cur - cpom[0]
dot = cpom[1].dot(vec)
if dot < 0.0: print(dot, 'inside')
else: print(dot, 'outside')
```

Answer (score 17):

let's look at the documentation for [*object.ray_cast(start, end)*](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=ray_cast#bpy.types.Object.ray_cast).

The ray_cast function returns 3 values:  *(location, normal, index)*:

> **location**, The hit location of this ray cast, float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf]
>
> **normal**, The face normal at the ray cast hit location, float array of 3 items in [-inf, inf]
>
> **index**, The face index, -1 when no intersection is found, int in [-inf, inf]

It will return the index of the first face encountered on the path between `start` and `end` Vectors.

- If the start vector is outside of the Object, and the face index is `-1`, you already know the point is not inside the object.
- But if it does return a face index, then you start counting how many consecutive faces it intersects by doing a ray_cast from the Vector of the  most recent intersection (plus a small offset towards the destination to push it away from the most recent face) to the end point.
- When at some point the face index returns -1, you know there are no more faces between the *checked point* and the *end point*, then you add up the total number of intersections.

  - If that number is even, it went in and out, and is currently out.
  - If it's odd, it's still inside.

In code that might look something like this:

```
def is_inside(ray_origin, ray_destination, obj):

    # the matrix multiplations and inversions are only needed if you
    # have unapplied transforms, else they could be dropped. but it's handy
    # to have the algorithm take them into account, for generality.
    mat = obj.matrix_local.inverted()
    f = obj.ray_cast(mat * ray_origin, mat * ray_destination)
    loc, normal, face_idx = f

    if face_idx == -1:
        return False
    
    max_expected_intersections = 1000
    fudge_distance = 0.0001
    direction = (ray_destination - loc)
    dir_len = direction.length
    amount = fudge_distance / dir_len
    
    i = 1
    while (face_idx != -1):
        
        loc = loc.lerp(direction, amount)    
        f = obj.ray_cast(mat * loc, mat * ray_destination)
        loc, normal, face_idx = f
        print(face_idx)
        if face_idx == -1:
            break
        i += 1
        if i > max_expected_intersections:
            break

    return not ((i % 2) == 0)
```

Here a test blend using Sverchok Scripted Node with that algorithm.

[image]

[image]

caveat: The fudge distance is not very nicely calculated, if might help precision to repeat the algorithm from a few randomly picked points around the object, and take the most common return value.

**edit:**
I just realized you can track the indices of intersected faces and adjust the fudge factor of the ray until the ray_cast no longer returns the index of a previously intersected face, letting it progress on..

#### Another approach

using [obj.closest_point_on_mesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=closest%20point#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_mesh). Offered by [Kosvor on sverchok issue tracker](https://github.com/nortikin/sverchok/issues/660#issuecomment-107022134):

```
def is_inside(p, max_dist, obj):
    # max_dist = 1.84467e+19
    point, normal, face = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(p, max_dist)
    p2 = point-p
    v = p2.dot(normal)
    print(v)
    return not(v < 0.0)
```

this assumes all faces of the object are pointing outwards

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please note: the [arguments for ray cast have changed](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.ray_cast) since this answer was written.

Answer (score 6):

A non node version

Here's a bmesh version I've been using for when the data isn't in a Mesh datatype.

```
from mathutils import Vector
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree

def are_inside(points, bm):
    """
    input: 
        points
        - a list of vectors (can also be tuples/lists)
        bm
        - a manifold bmesh with verts and (edge/faces) for which the 
          normals are calculated already. (add bm.normal_update() otherwise)
    returns:
        a list
        - a mask lists with True if the point is inside the bmesh, False otherwise
    """

    rpoints = []
    addp = rpoints.append
    bvh = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm, epsilon=0.0001)

    # return points on polygons
    for point in points:
        fco, normal, _, _ = bvh.find_nearest(point)
        p2 = fco - Vector(point)
        v = p2.dot(normal)
        addp(not v < 0.0)  # addp(v >= 0.0) ?

    return rpoints
```

[image]

Here I show a Vector Grid (points) and a Torus (a bmesh). The red dots are outside (False), and white dots are inside (True).

#### warning

- This doesn't produce desired results on low poly meshes.
- subdividing low poly meshes for the sake of inputting them into the algorithm, also doesn't work.

a better solution will come.

Comment: start with known point outside of mesh...ray_cast from outsize known point to test point.  At each find, move epsilon....ray_cast again until no intersection.  Odd number of intersections = inside, even number = outside.  Can test each corner of bounding box to avoid low angle errors "slipping through."  I plan to write this algorithm sometime soon :-)

Answer (score 4):

**If false-inside positives are important to you, consider the following tweak of the dot-product method**.

One issue with the dot-product method is that if the angle between the closest-face normal vector and point-closest-mesh-point vector is close to 90 degrees, rounding errors will result in some points that are outside of the mesh to be classified as inside.

Below method adds a `tolerance` (in degrees) parameter:

```
from math import pi, acos

def is_inside(target_pt_global, mesh_obj, tolerance=0.05):

    # Convert the point from global space to mesh local space
    target_pt_local = mesh_obj.matrix_world.inverted() * target_pt_global

    # Find the nearest point on the mesh and the nearest face normal
    _, pt_closest, face_normal, _ = mesh_obj.closest_point_on_mesh(target_pt_local)

    # Get the target-closest pt vector
    target_closest_pt_vec = (pt_closest - target_pt_local).normalized()

    # Compute the dot product = |a||b|*cos(angle)
    dot_prod = target_closest_pt_vec.dot(face_normal)

    # Get the angle between the normal and the target-closest-pt vector (from the dot prod)
    angle = acos(min(max(dot_prod, -1), 1)) * 180 / pi

    # Allow for some rounding error
    inside = angle < 90-tolerance

    return inside
```

The downside, however, is that due to the `tolerance` parameter, there might be some points that are inside the mesh that will be classified as outside (false negatives). Adjust `tolerance` based on your sensitivity to false-positives.

In my test with ~25K random points, **tolerance of 0.02 eliminated all false-positives** without any false-negatives.

Comment: I am trying to figure out if a point is inside an object. It's throwing the following errors - for the first line inside the function 

""Element-wise multiplication: not supported between 'Matrix' and 'Vector' types""

Comment: @Sourav I can't test this right now, but try replacing '*' with '@' in the first line. It looks like a blender 2.8 issue (see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129473/typeerror-element-wise-multiplication-not-supported-between-matrix-and-vect)

Comment: Yeah, the * has to be replaced with @. However, the script is producing tons of false positibe results for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
def insideMesh(x,y,z, mesh):
    p = Vector((x,y,z))
    max_dist = 1.0e+20
    hit, point, normal, face = mesh.closest_point_on_mesh(p, max_dist)
    p2 = point-p
    v = p2.dot(normal)
    return not(v < 0.0)
```

**E.G.**

```
def add_cube(x,y,z,r):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=r,location=(x, y, z))
    return bpy.context.active_object

#add cube with dimension = 10 on x,y,z
add_cube(0,0,0,5)
mesh =  bpy.data.objects['Cube']
print('inside: '+str(insideMesh(0,0,-5,mesh)))
#(0,0,-5) results true since mesh{x,y,z}  is bounded by  -r to r
```

> *`don't forget`*
>
> > import bpy
> > from mathutils import Vector

Comment: Been watching this one for the improvement.. but `closest_point_on_mesh` is quite expensive? If you're assuming the mesh is right-way-out and closed, won't shooting a ray down X do?

Comment: you 're right, couldn't get the coordinates to work correctly with the earlier ray cast approach so it had to be this

Answer (score 1):

i numpyfied the version of @zeffi

```
def numpy_apply_transforms(ob, co):
    m = np.array(ob.matrix_world)    
    mat = m[:3, :3].T 
    loc = m[:3, 3]
    return co @ mat + loc



def volume_boolean_data(vg_name, bool_name, reverse=True):

    _t = time.time()

    target_object = bpy.context.object
    bool_object   = bpy.data.objects[bool_name]

    #create mesh data
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(bool_object.data)
    bmesh.ops.transform(bm, matrix=bool_object.matrix_world, verts=bm.verts) #local to global coord
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    bvh = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm, epsilon=0.0001)

    _d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-_t)
    print(f"after bmesh {_d}")

    #create array of points
    l = len(target_object.data.vertices)
    points = np.zeros((l * 3), dtype=np.float, )
    target_object.data.vertices.foreach_get('co',points)
    points.shape = (l, 3, )
    points = numpy_apply_transforms(target_object, points) #local to global coord

    _d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-_t)
    print(f"after points apply transform {_d}")


    def check_if_inside(row):
        nonlocal bvh, reverse
        fco, normal, _, _ = bvh.find_nearest(row)
        p2 = fco - Vector(row)
        v  = p2.dot(normal)
        return v < 0.0

    def check_if_inside_reverse(row):
        nonlocal bvh, reverse
        fco, normal, _, _ = bvh.find_nearest(row)
        p2 = fco - Vector(row)
        v  = p2.dot(normal)
        return not v < 0.0

    if reverse: values = np.apply_along_axis(check_if_inside, 1,points)
    else: values = np.apply_along_axis(check_if_inside_reverse, 1,points)

    _d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-_t)
    print(f"after along axis in {_d}")

    if vg_name not in o.vertex_groups: 
           vg = o.vertex_groups.new(name=vg_name)
    else:  vg = o.vertex_groups[vg_name]

    for i, v in enumerate(values):
        vg.add([i], v, 'REPLACE')

    _d = datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.time()-_t)
    print(f"finished in {_d}")

    return
```

Comment: Can you provide an example how to use the `volume_boolean_data()` function. What is `o`? For example in my case scenario I would like to check if points of one object are inside (or overlapping with) another. First I randomly put some objects inside another and then I want to check whether the object in the new location is within the boundaries of another or not https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212266/randomly-distribute-objects-over-a-plane .

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_inside(point,ob):
    box_size = 0.15
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', 
location=point, scale=(box_size,box_size,box_size))
    box=bpy.data.objects[bpy.context.active_object.name]
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].operation = 'INTERSECT'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object =    ob
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Boolean")
        result = (box.dimensions.x >= box_size) and (box.dimensions.y >= box_size) and (box.dimensions.z >= box_size)
    return result
finally:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(box, do_unlink=True)
```

None of the other answers worked for me with an object that I imported from OBJ files, not sure if that was the cause.  The object was plane that was then made into  a mesh with solidify.  The above code is my hack that works, but is slow.

I use the following code to drive the method:
obj_object is the mesh.

The flipping of z with y is because I am targeting Table Top Simulator.
delta = 0.5

```
nb_x = math.floor(obj_object.dimensions.x / delta)
nb_z = math.floor(obj_object.dimensions.z / delta)

half_x = obj_object.dimensions.x / 2
half_z = obj_object.dimensions.z / 2
x = -half_x
while x <= half_x :
    z = -half_z
    while z <= half_z :
        p = mathutils.Vector((x, z, 0))
        if is_inside(p, obj_object) :
            print("{x=%f, y=%f}," % (x,z))
        z = z + delta
    x = x + delta
```