# How to find if a point is inside a CURVE

Tags: python, bezier-curves, sapling-addon

This question is a kind of follow up to this question [How to find if a point is inside a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31693/how-to-find-if-a-point-is-inside-a-mesh), just in a different context. That is how to basically apply the same thing for curve objects such as tree sapling or ivy curve (from sapling addon and ivygen addon.

I wouldn't prefer converting curve objects to meshes because of large number of them and doing so could quite burden the system memory and rendering time. Besides, converting takes time if you have to performs point-checking quite often.

Comment: Convert (a temporary copy of) the resulting curves to mesh first?

Comment: That would work. Just a bit of concern, would it burden the system when you have quite large number of objects need to be converted? And would converting take good amount of time. This is in the context of having so many objects and the point-checking operation is done excessively many times.

Comment: I am not experienced with scripting so I can't really be of much help here. I am guessing you would discard said temporary meshes afterwards, so no long-term performance impact would incur. Conversion itself is relatively quick, I think. Maybe loop over all relevant curves first, copy and convert all to mesh, join them into one single large mesh and do the checking only once. Discard large mesh afterwards

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's indeed a good idea. Thanks a lot.