# Check if vertex lies within closed volume

Tags: python, scripting

Is there a way to check if a vertex (or for that matter, any location) is inside the closed volume of some object?

Comment: Use a BVHTree (https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/mathutils.bvhtree.html) and get the nearest face(s) from the location. The find nearest functions return location, normal and face index. So from that you can check if the location is inside or out depending on the normal orientation returned. I'm not sure this handles all the possible configurations though.

Comment: [Related (possible duplicate)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31693/how-to-find-if-a-point-is-inside-a-mesh)

Comment: If you would like to see inside your objects, you can enable wireframe view by pressing Z. You can also hide some objects in your Outliner to see which object can be overlapping

Comment: Thanks batFinger, that is exactly what I was asking for! I guess my question can be deleted.