# OSL script node : detect if two object collides and output a bool

Tags: scripting, node-editor, shaders, osl

I would like to have a script node that would output a boolean depending of if two objects are intersecting or not.

The goals is to use it in a mix shader and to hide / show my object depending of the intersection (kind of a mask).

[image]

The available inputs of my script node should be two objects ("active" object and "mask" object); and the output should be a boolean (0 or 1) for the FAC of a mix shader.

After having read this, I think it is possible, but don't know Blender scripting good enough yet to achieve it.

- https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?390733-Generate-a-material-change-at-mesh-intersection
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9080/14306

Can anyone help ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does this actually need to be a script node or could it be achieved with other means - such as Dynamic Paint?

Comment: Hi Rich, I don't know about Dynamic Paint.  I added an image to improve my question. What do you think ?

Comment: Knowing that I would like to be able to "switch" the material of the inside voxels too, not only the "surface" of the pile.

Comment: Do you intend for the whole object (cube) to switch as soon as any of it intersected with the ‘mask’ or would only the intersecting bit be affected?

Comment: The whole object.

Comment: it's better to this with python and hide the geometry if it intersects with another object... specially because there are too many voxels, doing this in OSL is not a good ideia.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working on something that goes somewhere towards answering your problem.. don't take it too seriously, I'm only getting used to some of the quirks of OSL in Blender/Cycles: some of these conditionals may look unnecessary, but for example, if I don't *use* the 'hit' local variable, it won't work, even though I don't need to.

```
#include "stdosl.h"

shader Dipper(
    string Container = "",
    output int IsInside = 0
)

{      
    if  ( raytype("refraction") != 1 ) IsInside = 0;
    else{

        int ray_depth;
        getattribute("path:ray_depth", ray_depth);

        if  ( ray_depth % 2  != 0){

            string source_name;
            int hit;
            hit = trace (P,I);
            getmessage ("trace", "geom:name", source_name);

            if (hit==1){
                if (source_name == Container ){ 
                    IsInside =1;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

[image: Example Render]

You enter the name of your container object in the 'Container' input,(unquoted).

[image: Nodes]

I'm also pretty sure you could make the logic of this shader fail, without too much effort.

Comment: Awesome !!! I'll try that.  Just to be sure : OSL does not work on GPU ?

Comment: @gordie .. at the moment, you are not offered the option of OSL if you select GPU as your rendering device in Blender.

Comment: You could adapt this old script of mine. It works with materialsIDs, so you get a better control of what objects work as a mask and what objects should be rendered as normal. https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?329326-Multiple-transmissive-objects-as-just-one-surface&highlight=

Comment: Seems nice too. Also, what I wanted to achieve is to "toggle" the material change (eg. when the origin of the mesh is inside the "domain"); not to have a transition. Would it be possible ?

Comment: @Secrop - thanks for your ref, tider and more knowledgeable than mine; material IDs are the way to go. (I didn't even know you could retrieve them). One line has me stumped: 
{exteriorSurf=(myMaterialIndex==hitMaterialIndex)+hitFace;}
e.g. if myMaterialIndex != hitMaterialIndex and hitFace is True, (hit face was backfacing), then exteriorSurf evaluates to 1? So enclosed unlike materials are made transparent?
Maybe I've got the returns of {getmessage ("trace","backfacing" , var)} wrong. Where can you find the complete set of values that can be returned by {getmessage ("trace", "..." , var)}?

Comment: @gordie If you want to flip the entire material of an object when its origin is enclosed, maybe an approach like this one is better: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105789/update-values-of-objects-for-python-script/105897#105897

Comment: @gordie, I still think python is the best option (i.e. Robin's sugestion), as tracing rays is an expensive task.

Comment: @Robin Betts, the script is old.. from a  time I was still exploring OSL. just posted here to show that you can also probe materialsIDs, when tracing. For the full list of attributes you can retrieve from the message system, check the osl_services.cpp: https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/cycles.git/blob/HEAD:/src/kernel/osl/osl_services.cpp

Answer (score 0):

It's my first experience with OSL, so I can't say if this code has no bugs, but at first look it works as it should. I used source from Secrop's comment and adapted just as he advised.

```
surface Mask(
    closure color Surface = 0,
    output closure color Closure = 0
) {
    float visible = 0.0;
    float myMaterialIndex = 0.0;
    float hitMaterialIndex = 0.0;
    vector VectorTrace = vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    int Hit = 0;

    getattribute("material:index", myMaterialIndex);
    if(backfacing()) {
        VectorTrace -= I;
    } else {
        VectorTrace += I;
    }

    int DoTrace = trace(P, VectorTrace);

    if(DoTrace) {
        int HitTrace = getmessage("trace", "hit", Hit);

        if(Hit != 0) {
            HitTrace = getmessage("trace", "material:index", hitMaterialIndex);
        }

        visible = myMaterialIndex == hitMaterialIndex;
    }
    if(visible != 0) {
        Closure = Surface;
    } else {
        Closure = transparent();
    }
}
```

The setup consists of setting equal pass index for both objects materials and plugging script's node right before last node.

[image: Masked object material]

[image: Result]

Be aware that **any** objects, placed behind one with according material index, will block view at your masked object. It sounds obvious, but not really, when it comes to **transparent** objects too, even those that doesn't contain typical shader output but only volume output.

---

Ye, it doesn't return boolean, as author wanted, but at least it
solves that tricky problem, when you forced to use multiple render
layers and compositor...)