# OSL: Anomalous normals returned by getmessage("trace")

Tags: cycles-render-engine, scripting, osl

One approach to finding if a shading point P is inside another object in OSL includes firing a probe ray back towards the camera from P, and detecting, whether the first face encountered faces towards P, or away from it.

This involves finding the normal of the first hit face. According to the OSL specification, I would expect this to be expressed in "common" space, which in the Blender/Cycles implementation, is world space.

This shader, tN_anomaly, is essentially for debugging - it prints formatted information about P,  the probe ray fired from it, and the point hit by the ray.

```
#include "stdosl.h"

// DEBUG HELPER - return 1 with probability prob
int pRnd(float prob){ 

    int iP = int((noise("usimplex",P))*  1000000000) ; 
    int iI = int((noise("usimplex",I))*  1000000000) ;
    return( ((iP^iI ) % 1000000 ) < (1000000 * prob));

}

// DEBUG HELPER - return string repr of raytype(s)
string dbgRayTypes(){

    string sRT = "";

    if (raytype("camera")) sRT = concat(sRT,"[CAM]");
    if (raytype("diffuse")) sRT = concat(sRT,"[DIF]");
    if (raytype("glossy")) sRT = concat(sRT,"[GLS]");
    if (raytype("reflection")) sRT = concat(sRT,"[RFL]");
    if (raytype("refraction")) sRT = concat(sRT,"[RFR]");
    if (raytype("shadow")) sRT = concat(sRT,"[SHD]");
    if (sRT == "") sRT == "[NUL]";

    return sRT;
}

//SHADER START

shader tN_anomaly(      
       output int hitBackfacing = 0
)
{  
// fire a ray back towards the eye from the shading point
    if (trace(P,I)){

        // DEBUG INFO DUMP SETUP:

        // Built in to OSL ...
        // All following points and vectors in world space...
        // global -  P:  shading point of current object. 
        // global -  I:  vector from P to eye.
        // global -  N:  shading normal at shading point.
        // global -  Ng: true normal at shading point.

        // create containers for traced object´s values...

        string tObj; // name of object hit by the probe ray
        vector tI;   // vector from the probe ray´s hitpoint to P
        point  tP;   // point on target hit by the probe ray
        normal tN;   // shading normal at tP
        normal tNg;  // true normal at tP

        // Assign the corresponding values...

        getmessage ("trace", "geom:name", tObj);
        getmessage ("trace", "I", tI);
        getmessage ("trace", "P", tP);
        getmessage ("trace", "N", tN);
        getmessage ("trace", "Ng", tNg);
        // END SETUP


        // CALCULATE OUTPUT: Whether the hit mesh´s hit face was backfacing.
        //   If the normal of the first face hit is frontfacing to the camera, 
        //   (down I), it´s backfacing to us.

        if( dot(tN,I) > 0) hitBackfacing = 1;


        //PRINT DEBUG INFO for one in a thousand 'hit' rays
        //
        // Output style:
        //
        // | ray type: [RTP]
        // +----------------------+---------------------
        // |           self       |        hit: tObj
        // | I    Ix ,  Iy ,  Iy  |  tIx , tIy , tIz
        // | P    Px ,  Py ,  Pz  |  tPx , tPy , tPz
        // | N    Nx ,  Ny ,  Nz  |  tNx , tNy , tNz
        // | Ng   Ngx,  Ngy,  Ngz |  tNgx, tNgy, tNgz
        // | bf         ?bf       |        t?bf
        //
        // Where:
        //
        // [RTP] stands for the raytype flags produced by dbgRayTypes()
        //
        // Ix (and likewise) is the x component of I (etc.)
        // tIx (and likewise) is the x component of the hit object´s I (etc.)
        //
        //  ?bf is, whether P is viewed from the back, using backfacing()
        // t?bf is the output of the script, stored in hitBackfacing

        if (pRnd(0.001)){

            string dbg = format    ("\n\n| ray type: %5s\n", dbgRayTypes());
            dbg = concat(dbg, "+----------------------+---------------------\n");
            dbg = concat(dbg, format("| %14s%8s%13s%s","self","|","hit: ",tObj));
            dbg = concat(dbg, "\n| I");
            dbg = concat(dbg,format("%7.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",I[0],I[1],I[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, " | ");
            dbg = concat(dbg, format("%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",tI[0],tI[1],tI[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, "\n| P");
            dbg = concat(dbg,format("%7.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",P[0],P[1],P[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, " | ");
            dbg = concat(dbg, format("%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",tP[0],tP[1],tP[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, "\n| N");
            dbg = concat(dbg,format("%7.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",N[0],N[1],N[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, " | ");
            dbg = concat(dbg, format("%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",tN[0],tN[1],tN[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, "\n| Ng");
            dbg = concat(dbg,format("%6.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",Ng[0],Ng[1],Ng[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, " | ");
            dbg = concat(dbg, format("%5.2f,%5.2f,%5.2f",tNg[0],tNg[1],tNg[2]));
            dbg = concat(dbg, "\n| bf");
            dbg = concat(dbg,format("%12i",backfacing()));
            dbg = concat(dbg, "       | ");
            dbg = concat(dbg, format("%11i", hitBackfacing));

            printf ("%s\n\n",dbg);
            }
        //END PRINT
    }
}
```

In the illustrations, there are two unit cubes. The yellow cube is 0-1 in world X,Y and Z. It uses the shader in this node tree:

[image]

The hope is,that if the first face hit when probing back to the eye is backfacing with respect to the probe, the yellow cube will be shaded blue.

The pink cube's material is a simple tinted transparent BSDF. It's called 'TGT'.

OK, here's the first case. the camera is looking down Z. The pink cube is above the yellow cube, and clear of it, so you would expect the first normal to be encountered by the probe to be (0,0,-1).

[image]

A typical line printed by tN_anomaly is as follows:

```
| ray type: [CAM]
+----------------------+---------------------
|           self       |        hit: TGT
| I  -0.00,-0.00, 1.00 |  0.00, 0.00,-1.00
| P   0.96, 0.94, 1.00 |  0.96, 0.94, 1.15
| N   0.00, 0.00, 1.00 |  0.00, 0.00,-1.00
| Ng  0.00, 0.00, 1.00 |  0.00, 0.00,-1.00
| bf           0       |           0
```

So far, so good. The first face of the hit object, (TGT's P, second column) is in the right place, just above Z=1, and its normal (N or Ng, second column - these won't differ with flat shading) shows as (0,0,-1). The output (bf, second column) is thus as it ought to be as well.

Now the second case: this time the cubes overlap, so we would expect the first normal encountered to be (0,0,1).

[image]

The typical output is as follows:

```
| ray type: [CAM]
+----------------------+---------------------
|           self       |        hit: TGT
| I  -0.00,-0.00, 1.00 |  0.00, 0.00,-1.00
| P   0.96, 0.94, 1.00 |  0.96, 0.94, 1.80
| N   0.00, 0.00, 1.00 | -0.00,-0.00,-1.00
| Ng  0.00, 0.00, 1.00 | -0.00,-0.00,-1.00
| bf           0       |           0
```

Everything checks out: you can tell the right face of the pink cube is being hit (by looking at TGT's P in the second column). But TGT's normal (N or Ng, second column), is pointing the wrong way. And the output backfacing flag (bf, second column), which should now be 1, thus hasn't changed either, since it depends on the direction of N.

Can anyone on BSE give an innocent explanation .. or ..
If this is a bug, where should I post it / ask further about it?

Comment: That's quite a lot of effort, to get to the bottom of this. Thanks! I'll have to try it out myself to see it work. Where would the output be printed? I'm guessing into Blender's console?

Comment: @kram1032  The system console .. (Window>System Console) .. careful not to close the window, you'll close Blender. The format that results from the code is not quite as tidy as the one shown here, it's single long lines, not pairs of short lines. Easy enough to fix. keep the relevant 'hit' rendered area small ( a small number of pixels) to avoid printing too many lines, You can adjust the quantity by zooming in and out.

Comment: @kram1032   Thank you for your edits .. part of the reason for my choice of formatting was to make it easier for readers of this question to see there wasn't a typo by tabulating the format parameters _in the code_ - but your output is clearer. It's important to include Ng. The minimal case for exposing this anomaly is a pair of single faces, flipping the normals to test - (the same problem arises). **Are you sure `bf` is provided by OSL?** I can't find it in the spec, but you've managed to print it without defining it, so it must be coming from somewhere? With no docs, bf to what, I wonder?

Comment: I thought I read it somewhere, but I could be mistaken about bf. It definitely gives weird outputs. If that's because it's, in fact, undefined, and it behaves sort of randomly, then that's entirely my bad. It'd be easy enough to remove just those lines from the script though. And a traced backfacing check is simple enough to do regardless, as you demonstrated already with the original script. Perhaps it should just do it that way (showing you what output the script actually gave for that hit in the end) - I noticed, that certain view angles WILL make the output be 1.

Comment: Well, you haven't even declared 'bf'. So the compiler would definitely object if _someone_ hadn't given it to you... I would leave it in.. it might help figure out at what level the error is occurring. I suspect the weird result when using 'int' will be because the messaging system is set up to use fixed blocks of floating-point memory for speed and economy, and casts everything to 'float'. I'm _very_ interested in your exceptional cases .. I don't have time at the moment to try and reproduce them but  perhaps, some time, you can put up a Blend file which shows them.

Comment: Oh, well, trace doesn't really complain if a value doesn't exist, right? Certainly not at compile time. I figured, if the flag doesn't exist, it might give a bad memory location or something. I just pushed an edit to that effect. If you rather have it left in, perhaps just don't accept that edit. Though maybe make it an int, then, because, as mentioned in the script, the int value it outputs is really weird, and if I'd expect a potential bug to lie there somewhere.

Comment: Or if you are asking about bf of the source object, I.e. the output of `backfacing()`, that absolutely does exist. That I am sure of. I'm just not entirely sure whether you can do `getmessage("trace", "backfacing", tbf)`. I just called those "bf" so they fit into the table.

Comment: Ah, I remember where I read `getmessage("trace", "backfacing", tbf)` - that was used in Secrop's script here: https://blenderartists.org/t/multiple-transmissive-objects-as-just-one-surface/603321 - but I later determinded, that the corresponding check apparently did nothing, i.e. you could get rid of it without altering the script's behavior. And, crucially, same with the  `getmessage ("trace", "material:index" ,  hitMaterialIndex )` and later check there. It'd just apply the closures regardless of what material intersects.

Comment: Note, https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html "backfacing" isn't documented as an attribute proviced by Cycles. It might be an OSL standard though. And "material:index" *is* provided, so that should be working.

Comment: OK we're getting closer. This is [the code](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/cycles.git/blob/HEAD:/src/kernel/osl/osl_services.cpp) we should be looking at... well actually, we may have to go back further into the kernel.to find where the traced N is coming from.. but this file lists the services made available by `trace()`.. and "backfacing" isn't one of them. The returned 0 is a null result, so, yes, get rid of that call to `trace("backfacing")` and we'll do that bit by hand, using the faulty `Ng`.

Comment: That's exactly what my latest edit ended up doing. Thanks for the git link by the way. That's useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the Normal in OSL (and, in fact, standard cycles shader nodes) is that it *always* represents the normal on the same side as the *incident ray*. This provides for a consistency between ray interactions with a surface without having to worry about how the 'geometry normal' is oriented.

In order to determine which face (inside or outside) the ray has 'hit' you need to use the 'backfacing' property. In Cycles nodes this would be provided by the Geometry node but in OSL you can use the 'backfacing()' function.

For example :

```
shader backfacing_shader(
    output color Col = 0
  ){

    if (backfacing())
    {
        Col = color(1,0,0);   // Red on the inside
    }
    else
    {
        Col = color(0,1,0);   // Green on the outside
    }
}
```

This means that to get your desired behaviour you need to check the `backfacing()` result and flip the direction of your normal if this returns a non-zero value.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean too .. that's why I deleted the original comment.  `N` and `Ng` always return a vector pointing towards the ray origin, in whatever context, so they can't be used to discriminate between front and back facing faces. At least now we know that's policy, not bug, so thanks.

Comment: @Robin  :: Does it really work for you?  It doesn't for me.   Are you sure that  `backfacing()` is information from the `trace()` function call, and not from `P`?

Comment: @cppBeginner :: (love the cpp double-colon) ... this is going back some way for me, so would involve reconstructing some lost .blends to be sure.. my approach would be to set up minimal test-cases.. maybe if you do that, you could post a contrary example as another question? I'll have another look, when I can.

Comment: @Robin :: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184868/check-whether-trace-collide-a-face-at-back-or-front-side , thanks.