# check whether `trace()` collide a face at back or front side?

Tags: osl

How to check whether `trace(ray,direction,...)` collides the nearest face at ***front** OR **back** side*?

According to [OSL: Anomalous normals returned by getmessage("trace")](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109998/osl-anomalous-normals-returned-by-getmessagetrace/110052?noredirect=1#comment309681_110052), these below codes won't work because it always return value as front-face (automatically flipped) from ray's perspective.

```
getmessage ("trace", "N", tN);
getmessage ("trace", "Ng", tNg);
```

The same link suggests that `backfacing()` is the solution.
However, it doesn't work.  I will show a test case below.

I have 2 cubes.

[image]

Here is my OSL shader of `CubeA`.
For every point of `CubeA`, shoot +z ray, and check whether the ray touches `CubeB` at `CubeB`'s back-face (return green) or front-face (return red).

```
#include "stdosl.h"
shader tN_anomaly
[[ string help = "" ]]
(      
    output vector hitBackfacing = vector(0,0,0)
){
    hitBackfacing=vector(0,0,0);  
    if (trace(P,vector(0,0,1))){
        string tObj;
        getmessage ("trace", "geom:name",tObj);
        if(tObj=="CubeB"){
            hitBackfacing=vector(1,0,0);
            if(backfacing()){
                hitBackfacing=vector(0,1,0); //: never reach
            };
            
        }
    }

}
```

The below image is the result.  It suggests that `backfacing()` always return `false`.
It looks like to me that the `backfacing()` just cares about whether it is back-face from **eye** perspective, not from the most recent **`trace()`**'s perspective.

Left image = they are overlapping each other. (The correct result should be green.)
Right image = `CubeB` is above `CubeA` (not touching)
[image]

Here is my blend file.
[image]

Here is another blend file.  It is very similar, but I stretch `Cube2` in x&y axis to cover the whole `Cube1`.  It also prints log z which **> 1**.

[image]

Comment: I'm stumped. The information we need is `backfacing`, as determined by the clockwise / anticlockwise order of vertices around the polygon containing the shading point, from the ray's POV. The only way I can find of accessing this information is via the `backfacing()` function, but that can only be called on the shaded P, not on a P we hit ourselves, with a probing ray. I've tried vertex locations, dPdu,dPdv.. .... all sorts.

Comment: @Robin :: Thank.  It gives me some idea.   Perhaps "geom:trianglevertices" might be useful.   I am investigating.  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html  ... yea, look like it works.

Comment: @Robin I can use clockwise/counter-clockwise check (cross-product).  In my simple test, it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Robin  Here is the nutshell : `point ps[3];   getmessage("trace","geom:trianglevertices",ps); vector trueNormal= cross(ps[1]-ps[0],ps[2]-ps[0]);` I need to test more.

Comment: Fantastic. Example [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GEoObKwB/)

Comment: @Robin :: Nice example. Thanks. You can post answer if you want. I don't plan to do. I am too satisfied for now. If you didn't say about `dPdu`, I couldn't reach this point of knowledge.  Your original question is really good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really @cppBeginner's answer to his own post.. (see commentary on OP).

The `backfacing()` function can be called on the implicit shading point in an OSL script, but is not available as an attribute returned in a message from a script-cast ray.

But many [mesh and object attributes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html#attributes) can be returned by OSL's `trace()`. See `getmessage ("trace", ...)` in the [OSL specification](https://github.com/imageworks/OpenShadingLanguage/blob/master/src/doc/osl-languagespec.pdf).. this page of [Blender source](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/kernel/osl/osl_services.cpp$78) might help with types, etc.. (but that's only a grep, I don't strictly know how it ties in. Maybe someone can edit to flesh that out.)

These attributes include `geom:trianglevertices`,  which is an array of three 3D points: the coordinates in World space of the corners of the render-triangle containing the shading point. They appear to be in order, so the cross-product of two edges can be taken to find the direction of the triangle's normal, as defined by the mesh.

```
#include "stdosl.h"
shader Hit_Backfacing
(    
    vector RayDir = vector(0.0),
    output int Hit = 0,
    output int Hit_Backfacing = 0
){
    if (trace(P,rayDir)){
    
        Hit = 1;  
        vector triNormal = vector(0.0);
        point  triVerts[3];
        
        getmessage("trace","geom:trianglevertices",triVerts);
        triNormal = cross(triVerts[1]-triVerts[0],triVerts[2]-triVerts[0]); 
        
        Hit_Backfacing = dot(triNormal,rayDir) > 0;    
    }
}
```

In this example, the sign of dot-product of that normal and the cast ray direction tells us whether the triangle we hit faces us, or not...

[image]

The large plane carries the illustrated material.

[image]