# Make an object disappear by moving through a mesh

Tags: masking

is it possible for me to make an object disappear by making it move through a mesh. For an example. I have a car modeling, and i want it to disappear after the end of the road. I don't want the car to suddenly disappear like turning off the visibility or restrict rendering. I want the mesh to work like a mask for the car. So that when the car go through the mesh. It will vanish. I'm sorry i am bad at explaining. I hope the image can help me a little bit.[image]

Comment: a Boolean maybe?

Comment: WIll it work for a moving object?

Comment: yes of course, but you'll have to give the Boolean modifier to each object that is part of your car

Comment: Do you need to see the newly cut faces / the inside of your car, as it disappears? Or do you plan on the angle being more or less as shown?

Comment: I want the whole car to disappears as it going out of the camera. Btw i am doing a Isometric 3D modeling.

Comment: The OSL route [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109614/fake-bool-operation-with-osl-shader)  _might_ help, but it might be too complicated for what you need .. and/or the model might not be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **Boolean** modifier:

- Create a cube. It will be the object that will make your car disappear.
- In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display*, choose *Maximum Draw Type* > *Wire*. In the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Cycles Settings* > *Ray Visibility*, disable everything. Your cube is now transparent in both *Object* and *Render* mode.
- Select your car, give it a *Boolean* modifier, choose Operation > *Difference*, and choose the cube as the *Object*.
- Now when you move your car, the part that touches the cube becomes invisible.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I will try to use the technique and make sure wether it will work or not.