# How to clip a material and give the illusion that it is 'solid' or 'filled' with Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I am using a combination of Cycles material shaders to perform a "clipping" view for a geologic cross-section. The answers to the following question  explain very well how to achieve the cut-away view.

[How can I easily animate cutaway views on multiple objects?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8600/how-can-i-easily-animate-cutaway-views-on-multiple-objects)

The difference between these answers and what I am looking for is that with these you can look inside the mesh. I would like to give the illusion of a solid or filled mesh. Even if it appears to be filled with something like colored smoke.

I'm trying to cut hundreds of objects, and cut multiple X-sections (e.g. clip the Y-axis from 90-110, and 190-210, 290-310, etc).

This is an example of an original mesh that I would like to clip:
[image: Original Unclipped Mesh]

This is what I would like to accomplish. I did this using boolean modifiers. The problem with this method is it does not scale well to many objects, nor is it simple to make multiple X-sections.
[image: Target Outcome]

This is where I currently am using Cycles nodes. 
[image: Cycles Nodes]

This is the node tree with two groups:
[image: Cycles Node Tree]
[image: Clipping Group 1]
[image: Clipping Group 2]

I believe that a volume or emission node may be able to provide this effect. I have tried adding it in a variety of places.

Placing the volume absorption node right before the material output:
[image: Volume absorption before output]

[image: Result 1]

Placing the volume absorption node between the diffuse node the first location group results in this:
[image: Volume absorption after diffuse node]
[image: Result 2]

Is it possible to have this geographically clipped material appear to be solid or filled with smoke?

Comment: OSL, so CPU only, but this may be of interest: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110078/35559

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do it manually.

1) Press **TAB** to go into edit mode.

2) Select all the vertices bordering the hole.

[image]

3) Press 'F' to fill the selected area.

[image]

I hope this helps! -Galaxy

Comment: I'm afraid that, similar to the boolean modifier, this does not scale well to many objects.