# is it possible to change a material depending on whether it is intersecting with another object?

Tags: materials, geometry

Let's say I have a sphere, halfway intersecting with a cube(which is invisible to the camera). I want to change the material of the part of the sphere that is intersecting with the box, similar to this image:

[image: like this]

Comment: With a cube, it wouldn't be necessary, but in some situations, [OSL might help](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/110078/35559)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create 2 spheres on the exact same position, each with its own texture, then 1 cube. Give each sphere a *Boolean* modifier, one with the *Difference* mode, the other with the *Intersect* mode, and both with the cube as *Object*. This way, when you'll move the cube, it will both hide a sphere and reveal the other one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this method, (which also happened to be the way I made the reference image, so I'm just dumb)

Comment: Could work with only one cube, I think. using intersection and difference.

Comment: oh yes of course, I'm going to correct

Answer (score 10):

An update, thanks to [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) comments:

It is possible using Cycles:

[image]

The shader simply tests if the transparent depth is at least 1 as the cube is transparent but also we don't want more than one (as if not the cube shape may appear in non ortho views):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought you had the solution but actually what you propose is to display another texture through the cube transparency, which is not exactly what he's looking for, at least it's what I understand

Comment: @moonboots, don't get what you mean

Comment: Could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots, sure: updated above

Comment: so yes, that's what I thought, actually the new texture is not displayed at the objects intersection but where the transparency happens, which is not the same... On the left what is supposed to happen, on the right what happens with your method: https://www.zupimages.net/up/19/36/tl1c.jpg

Comment: @moonboots, you are right.

Comment: @moonboots, corrected