# Change material on part of object with other overlapping object

Tags: materials, shaders

I learned this trick sometime ago but I have forgot.  So what I want to do is add different material to an object using other object. For example I have two cubes. One has red material and one has blue material. By overlapping those cubes I'd want the material on the overlapping part of the red cube to turn into blue.
[image: Sample image below. Actual use would be far more complex case with no matching edges to manually set materials]
Sample image below. Actual use would be far more complex case with no matching edges to manually set materials

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create 2 overlapping cubes. Create somewhere a third cube that will be the boolean object and make it invisible in render. Give your 2 first cubes 2 different colors, give them both a *Boolean* modifier with the third cube as *Object*. For the orange cube, choose the *Difference* option, for the blue one, choose *Intersect*.

[image]

Comment: That works. I'll wait if someone can post something that doesn't require duplicate objects

Comment: I also noticed this harms the vertex normals of the meshes, requiring some extra work to fix those issues

Comment: yes, that's not ideal because boolean can be a bit tricky, it should work better in next versions of Blender. A similar question has been asked a long time ago, I'll try to find...

Comment: This is actually pretty nice trick, too bad i suffers from boolean issues in some cases. Even multiple materials is not that difficult as one can assign different materials to different parts manually to the hidden mesh that is revealed by the boolean object

Comment: so here is the question I was referring to, which is the same as yours, @lemon answered with another solution, I didn't test his answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151049/is-it-possible-to-change-a-material-depending-on-whether-it-is-intersecting-with/151059#151059

Comment: so I've tested, lemon's solution is not exactly what you want, but it may work for some projects