# Get bmesh and list of vertices

Tags: python, bmesh

I try to get the `are_inside` function working from:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/80781/21443

No matter what I try, I just get new errors.
My scene is as follows:

[image]

I don't want to rely on edit mode for selections for the script.

The closest I got is:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import bmesh


def are_inside(points, bm):
    """
    input: 
        points
        - a list of vectors (can also be tuples/lists)
        bm
        - a manifold bmesh with verts and (edge/faces) for which the 
          normals are calculated already. (add bm.normal_update() otherwise)
    returns:
        a list
        - a mask lists with True if the point is inside the bmesh, False otherwise
    """

    rpoints = []
    addp = rpoints.append
    bvh = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm, epsilon=0.0001)

    # return points on polygons
    for point in points:
        fco, normal, _, _ = bvh.find_nearest(point)
        p2 = fco - Vector(point)
        v = p2.dot(normal)
        addp(not v < 0.0)  # addp(v >= 0.0) ?

    return rpoints



def test():
    print("test")

    mesh_points = bpy.data.objects['Grid'].to_mesh()
    bm_points = bmesh.new()
    bm_points.from_mesh(mesh_points)
    points = bm_points.verts


    mesh = bpy.data.objects['Suzanne'].to_mesh()
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh(mesh)

    inside = are_inside(points, bm)

test()
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 4):

**Set  the points to a collection of coords.**

Needed to change to the points from a collection of `bmesh.types.BMVert` to a collection of 3d coordinates.

```
points = [v.co.copy() for v in bm_points.verts]
```

May still need some tests, here is the result

[image]

added some code such that if the grid is in edit mode, select the result.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
import bmesh


def are_inside(points, bm):
    """
    input: 
        points
        - a list of vectors (can also be tuples/lists)
        bm
        - a manifold bmesh with verts and (edge/faces) for which the 
          normals are calculated already. (add bm.normal_update() otherwise)
    returns:
        a list
        - a mask lists with True if the point is inside the bmesh, False otherwise
    """

    rpoints = []
    addp = rpoints.append
    bvh = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm, epsilon=0.0001)

    # return points on polygons
    for point in points:
        fco, normal, _, _ = bvh.find_nearest(point)
        p2 = fco - Vector(point)
        v = p2.dot(normal)
        addp(not v < 0.0)  # addp(v >= 0.0) ?

    return rpoints



def test(grid, ob):
    print("test")
    mesh_points = grid.to_mesh()
    bm_points = bmesh.new()
    bm_points.from_mesh(mesh_points)
    points = [v.co.copy() for v in bm_points.verts]


    mesh = ob.data
    bm = bmesh.new()

    bm.from_mesh(ob.to_mesh())

    inside = are_inside(points, bm)
    if grid.mode == 'EDIT':
        # view the result
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(grid.data)

        for v, select in zip(bm.verts, inside):
            v.select = select
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(grid.data)

scene = bpy.context.scene
test(scene.objects["Grid"], scene.objects["Suzanne"])
```

Consider using `bmesh_from_object()` or applying the global transform to the bmesh.  If using an edit mode bmesh and not wanting to commit changes `bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me).copy()` provides an unbound copy.

If only the transform needed then transforming a mesh copy with

```
me.transform(ob.matrix_world)
```

or using the operator, will provide global coordinates.

```
bmesh.ops.transform(bm,
        matrix=ob.matrix_world,
        verts=bm.verts)
```

Alternatively could put one in the object space of the other to make their coordinates equivalent.

The mesh provided from `ob.to_mesh()` is *"not what it used to be"*

[How do I get a mesh data-block with modifiers and shape keys applied in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender)

May be worth noting too that Suzanne has 3 separate parts.

Comment: Thanks, eventually I used animation nodes, which was more easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using animation nodes, here is my solution.

[image]

```py
from mathutils import Vector
import time

FLB = 0
FLT = 1
BLB = 2
BLT = 3
FRB = 4
FRT = 5
BRB = 6
BRT = 7


start = time.time()



def map(val, in_low, in_high, out_low, out_high):
    return out_low + (out_high - out_low) * ((val - in_low) / (in_high - in_low))


def lerp(vector_a, vector_b, t):
    return (1 - t) * vector_a + t * vector_b


VectorList = []


for z in range(X_Steps):

    t_z = float(z) / (X_Steps-1)

    lt = lerp(Corners[FLT], Corners[BLT], t_z)
    lb = lerp(Corners[FLB], Corners[BLB], t_z)
    rt = lerp(Corners[FRT], Corners[BRT], t_z)
    rb = lerp(Corners[FRB], Corners[BRB], t_z)

    for y in range(Y_Steps):

        t_y = float(y) / (Y_Steps-1)

        v1 = lerp(lt, lb, t_y)
        v2 = lerp(rt, rb, t_y)

        for x in range(X_Steps):

            t_x = float(x) / (X_Steps-1)

            v = lerp(v1, v2, t_x)
            VectorList.append(v)

print(time.time() - start)
```

[image]

[image]